# How to write value into current worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to write value into current worksheet?

Below will open a new worksheet.

```
sub test()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlSht = xlWb.Sheets(1)

    With xlSht
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Received Time"
    End With
 Call DocumentFolders(Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox), 2)
```

I tried to modified to this but it is not working. Any wrong with my code?

```
sub test()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws 'xlSht
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Received Time"
    End With

Call DocumentFolders(Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox), 2)
```

Comment: Where are you calling this code from?

Comment: @bigben sorry it is from excel vba

Comment: You said that it is _not working_, but you did not mention how it doesn't. Any error message? Is the sheet you are trying to write into protected?

Comment: the result will open into a new workbook. i wanted it to be in the same workbook. not a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is just to write on a Worksheet, then you can use this one:

```
Public Sub myTest()
Dim xlWb As Workbook
Dim xlWs As Worksheet

    Set xlWb = Application.Workbooks.Add   '<--- Create the New Workbook
    Set xlWs = xlWb.Sheets.Add    '<--- Create the Worksheet

    With xlWs
        .Range("A1") = "Received Time"  '<--- Write on First Sheet, Range A1
        
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Another Received Time"  '<--- Do the same but on Range B1
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Tsiriniaina I tried this but it still open up a new workbook. My current process, in excel > ALT F11 and paste my VBA script there > i want the result in the same excel Sheet1, not a new workbook.